Copy/paste issue Ubuntu Server
so i downloaded ubuntu server a few days ago to use mongo. Everything works fine, but i cant figure out how to copy text from my machine (macbook) and paste into the virtual machine system. My laptop is Macbook Pro 2017, i am using VMware Fusion as a virtual machine, and Ubuntu server. i have installed the VMware fusion tools (which were supposed to let me copy and paste), i checked the settings in my Virtual Machine, and everything seems to be enabled for copying/pasting between my machine and the virtual one. What can be the problem here? How can i achieve copy and pasting?

So long as the VM’s Client Isolation rules allow for copy/paste with the host, it should be possible to use Ctrl+Shift+V to paste and Ctrl+Shift+C to copy

Almost all settings for VMs are made on the host OS so are done on whatever OS your macbook is using.  How does virtualbox relate? as Oracle (virtualbox) & VMWare are different companies offering different [competing] products; they don't do everything the same.  I'll suggest working out what you're actually using.
